# Looping through folder to read pdf files

Tags: python, loops, pdf

So I've this code which worked file for the individual pdf file. but is not working when i added loop. as I wanted to loop through multiple pdf files in folder --> subfolders -->pdf files.
In path I'm not giving subfolders.

```
import fitz
import os
path = "/users/folder"

for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith(".pdf"):
       with fitz.open(path) as doc:
          text = ""
          for page in doc:
              text += page.getText().strip()
          return text
```

Comment: If you want to recursively iterate over subfolders you need to use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk).  Otherwise you can just do `listdir` on each of the specific subfolders that you care about (which themselves could come from a top-level `listdir` if you don't want to list them out explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to open "path" variable as a file.
Try this:

```
import fitz
import os
path = "/users/folder"

for i in os.listdir(path):
    if i.endswith(".pdf"):
       with fitz.open(path + "/" + i) as doc:
          text = ""
          for page in doc:
              text += page.getText().strip()
          return text
```

Comment: thanks this worked but it only did for the one pdf file not all.

Comment: yeah that is because you are returning the text after you are done with the first file. You should create an array and after each loop you should append the text to that array.

Comment: but that text is too long for a normal jupyter notebook to handle? I've some 200+ pdfs which I needed to convert to text, each one has 100k+ word count. Would I be able to run this in AWS EC2?

edit: this is for my research project which I need to do.

Comment: than you can create text files inside the loop.

Comment: inside the loop as in?

Comment: yes. create  different text files for each pdf file and add the text.

Answer (score 0):

Get a list of pdf files to process.

The following code has been tested for syntax. There are no errors.

However, it has not been tested for logical errors due to a lack of test files.

```
import fitz
import os

pdf_files = []
path = "/users/folder"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    # root will initially = path
    # Next loop root will become the next subdirectory which is found
    for directory in dirs:
        for file in files:
            # All files in the current root will be checked
            if file.endswith(".pdf"):
                pdf_files.append(os.path.join(directory, file))  # absolute path

for file in pdf_files:
    with fitz.open(path) as doc:
        text = ""
        for page in doc:
            text += page.getText().strip()
```

Comment: this worked but it only got the one file. Not all. how do i get all the files and maybe append it in a list? I'm converting the pdf into text format and then getting the text analysis using textatistic and then putting into dataframe but it is only giving one pdf file not all.

Comment: @Mick, the answer has been updated per the previous comment.

Comment: @Mick, I think logical errors have been fixed.